# Is there any way to upload directory with Tags for all the files using MultipleFileUpload Interface to s3 Bucket - aws sdk

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Is there any way to upload a directory with Tags for all the files  using MultipleFileUpload Interface - AWS SDK

I am able to upload the directory with all the files to s3 bucket,but not able to find proper references to add tags to all the sub-files inside the directory while uploading it to s3 bucket

Code :

```
 TransferManager xfer_mgr = TransferManagerBuilder.standard().withS3Client(getAmazonS3Client()).build();

             MultipleFileUpload xfer = xfer_mgr.uploadDirectory(getStorageName(),
                     trgtFolder, srcfolder, true);
       
             XferMgrProgress.showTransferProgress(xfer);
         
             XferMgrProgress.waitForCompletion(xfer);
```

- any reference for adding the tags for all sub files in the directory using  MultipleFileUpload uploadDirectory would be help